# Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache error after leaving login page for more than a minute

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Whenever I leave the login page for more than one minute, and then try to login, i am getting the following error:

Authentication error! Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.

And the logs are saying the following:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2019-09-26 11:15:46,065] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} - Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache
```

I've already enabled the Session Persistence on identity.xml , even tried changing the values of the

```
<TimeConfig>
<SessionIdleTimeout>15</SessionIdleTimeout>
<RememberMeTimeout>20160</RememberMeTimeout>
</TimeConfig>
```

Are there any files that can over write this option? Right now, the session timeout is after a minute and I can't figure out where to modify this.I already modified the setting on the management console on the web user interface.

Comment: What is the IS version that you are using?